# What is the MVC model for constructing a user profile, specifically, when to choose between UIViewController and UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

*I hope that this question is not down voted for not being specific enough because I believe that this question is very specific (about a general, sometimes-ambiguous concept).*

When creating a user profile, for example, how strictly should (or could) the MVC model be adhered to, and what are, if any, best practices for developing this type of screen when it comes to "controller" versus "view"?

As I started the UIViewController (below), I asked myself why the UIViewController was drawing the profile interface when everything I read about MVC said that the profile interface was a *view*, not a *controller*. The *controller's* responsibility, as I understand it, is handling functionality like grabbing data from a *model* file in the bundle and dealing with navigation.

**UIViewController**

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set background color
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // load banner
        banner(profileHasCustomBanner: false)

    }

    // banner
    func banner(profileHasCustomBanner: Bool) {
        let bannerHeight: CGFloat = profileHasCustomBanner ? 300 : 150
        let bannerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: bannerHeight))
        bannerImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-image")
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(bannerImageView)
    }

}
```

In the example above, the UIViewController has a UIView in it (the profile's banner image). But isn't the *view* supposed to be a separate file containing all of that screen's views? But, then again, the banner relies on data about the user to draw its interface, so it must pass through the controller, so the banner *does* belong in the *controller*, right?

I want to adhere to the MVC model as much as possible, so how is a user profile "supposed" to be approached? What, specifically, is the UIViewController supposed to handle about the user profile and what specifically is the UIView supposed to handle?

**UIView**

```
class UserProfileView: UIView {

    // do all user profile UIViews go here?
    // is this supposed to be a separate file from the file that contains the UIViewController?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adhere to MVC strictly and subclass every UIView (e.g UserProfileView), or if it's just something simple, you can create the view right there in the ViewController code.

Rule of thumb, you only really need to subclass when you feel you're going to be using that view in multiple places (e.g. across the app in various controllers, like a custom alertView), where you're getting some free functionality from the subclass, or where another element is expecting a view of that specific class, like a custom UITableViewCell.

Practically, it's a case of weighing up the costs (time, complexity) and benefits of creating a custom class for the UIView, as well as a fair bit of personal coding preferences.